# Add two variables inside style block Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to put two variables inside a style block in Reactjs. How do you go about doing this?

```
var GlobalStyles = require(./jsStyles/GlobalStyles.js);
var moduleSpecificStyles = {
    hide:{
        'display':'none'
    },
    //more styles
};

...

render:function(){
    return (
        ...
        <div style={GlobalStyles.container, moduleSpecificStyles.hide}></div>
    )
}
```

This does not seem to work. It will work on either one if I only have one in. But adding both, I am not sure how to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compose style objects together, if you're using ES2015 then you can use `Object.prototype.assign` function.

`<div style={Object.assign({}, GlobalStyles.container, moduleSpecificStyles.hide)}></div>`

No matter whether your `GlobalStyles.container` object has a `display: block` property value or not, the composed style object will have `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

The style prop expects a single object with key value pairs. See [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html) for more.

If you want to combine the two, then use `Object.assign` [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
render() {
   var style = Object.assign({}, GlobalStyles.container, moduleSpecificStyles.hide)
   return <div style=={style}></div>
}
```